# derivative of $y = |x|$ and contradiction with the intermediate value property

Tags: functions, derivatives

The Unit step function(derivative of $y = |x|$) does not take the values from $(0, 1)$. It is said that this function cannot be a derivative of any real valued function. But isn't $y = |x|$ a real valued function, whose domain and range are both real numbers? So, how is this unit step function not a derivative of any real valued function?

Comment: Oh, I think you mean the Heaviside Function...but that is **not** the derivative of the absolute value function, but rather of the ramp function $\;\max\{x,0\}\;$ , very different from $\;|x|\;$ ...

Comment: The $| \cdot |$ function is not differentiable at $0$. Although it has a derivative - the $\operatorname{sgn}$ function - in the distributional sense.

Comment: @DonAntonio , I don't know about the heaviside function , see this: http://pasteboard.co/M5k4qAlYo.png

Comment: @Andrew, the |.| function? if f = |x| then |x|/x = f', see: http://pasteboard.co/M5k4qAlYo.png

Comment: The fundamental theorem of calculus requires the original function (i.e. the derivative) to be continuous. Both the Heaviside step function and the sign function are discontinuous at a particular point

Comment: @BumbleBee: [No function with a jump discontinuity is a derivative.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux's_theorem_%28analysis%29) As Andrew says, the absolute value function is not differentiable at $0$. Consequently, if $I$ is an open interval containing $0$, then "$f(x) = |x|$ is not differentiable on $I$", despite the fact that $f'(x) = x/|x|$ for all $x \neq 0$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang , um, a bit confused. Could you first absolutely confirm to me that: "**Is y = |x| a real valued function**"?

Comment: I mean the range of it are real values

Comment: Yes, the absolute value function (whose graph has equation $y = |x|$) is a real-valued function.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang , thomas' calculus states that the unit step function cannot be a derivative of any real valued function, and it takes the indermediate value property thorem as it's base for saying so. But, the derivative of the absolute value function y = |x| is h = |x|/x, which is also a step function(though not a _unit_ step function. I am asking how this is possible. (see: http://pasteboard.co/M8uL5vcCc.png)

Answer (score 2):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\abs}{abs}$By definition, a real-valued function $f$ defined on some non-empty open set $I$ is *differentiable* on $I$ if $f$ is differentiable at $x$ for every $x$ in $I$.

Let $\abs(x) = |x|$ for $x$ real. The difference quotient at $0$ is
$$
\frac{\abs(h) - \abs(0)}{h} = \frac{|h|}{h},\quad h \neq 0.
$$
Since the difference quotient has no limit as $h \to 0$ (the one-sided limits exist but are unequal), $\abs'(0)$ does not exist. That is, the absolute value function is not differentiable at $0$.

Consequently, the absolute value function is "not differentiable" on any open interval containing $0$, e.g., is not differentiable on the set of real numbers. The fact that $\abs'(x)$ exists for all $x \neq 0$ is immaterial.

Careful examination of the intermediate value property for derivatives reveals that the domain of $f$ must be an *interval*. The absolute value function does not contradict the intermediate value property: the function $\abs'(x) = |x|/x$ for $x \neq 0$ fails to satisfy the intermediate value property on a non-empty open real interval $I$ if and only if $0 \in I$, if and only if $\abs$ is not differentiable on $I$.